# Why does JPAComponentPresentationDAO have 2 remove methods?

Tags: 2011, storage-extensions

The storage DAO class JPAComponentPresentationDAO has two remove methods:

```
public void remove(ComponentPresentation itemToRemove, ComponentPresentationTypeEnum 
    componentPresentationType)
    throws StorageException

public void remove(int publicationId, int componentId, int componentTemplateId, 
    ComponentPresentationTypeEnum componentPresentationType)
    throws StorageException
```

Does anyone know why there are two? I find that only the second method is ever called, but should I also override the first when I implement by own storage DAO?

Comment: No idea. I've never seen it being triggered. But to be sure, just call your custom code from that method as well. ;)

Answer (score 9):

The override that expects a Component Presentation is just a wrapper for the one that expects the ids. For Instance this override expects a `publicationId`, `componentId` and `componentTemplateId`:

```
public void remove(int publicationId, int componentId, int componentTemplateId,
                   ComponentPresentationTypeEnum componentPresentationType)
    throws StorageException
{
    ComponentPresentation foundComponentPresentation = getComponentPresentation(
        publicationId, componentId, componentTemplateId, componentPresentationType);
    if(foundComponentPresentation != null)
    {
        log.debug("Removing component presentation from storage.");
        super.remove(foundComponentPresentation);
    } else
    {
        log.debug("Could not find component presentation to remove from storage.");
    }
}
```

This other override expects a ComponentPresentation so that we can call the first override from this one.

```
public void remove(ComponentPresentation itemToRemove, 
                   ComponentPresentationTypeEnum componentPresentationType)
    throws StorageException
{
    remove(itemToRemove.getPublicationId(), itemToRemove.getComponentId(),
           itemToRemove.getTemplateId(), componentPresentationType);
}
```

I think it is just for **code re-usability** since the real implementation is in the first one.